# Terminology for system of equations and...

Tags: notation, terminology, ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, model-theory

I am looking for the standard term for a system that consists of things of the form 
$p_i(x_1,\ldots ,x_n)=0$ and of the form $q_j(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\neq 0$ with the $p_i$ and $q_j$ polynomials.  I have seen used the term "system of equations and inequalities" but to me inequality means "$\leq$" or "$\geq$" and not "$\neq$" so I would prefer not to use it.  Is there some commonly accepted term?

I made this CW since I am not sure there is a correct answer.

Comment: See "semialgebraic set" ... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semialgebraic_set  ... in that setting, of course, $q_j \ne 0$ is the same as $q_j^2 > 0$.

Comment: Also search for inequations.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2012.04.07

Comment: I've also seen the term "disequality" or "disequation".  

Comment: The situation for semi-algebraic sets is different since inequality ends up being about the order. But to me when there is no order inequation or disquality. Sound better. But I would feel better to not use an ad hoc term. So I am hoping to hear an official term if possible. 

Comment: These are called "equations and inequations" in the literature related to first order theories (say, Tarski problem and such). 

Comment: Ok, I think I will stick with Mark's answer then.

Comment: There's also the standard trick of introducing auxiliary variables $y_j$ and replacing each nequation $q_j(x_1,\ldots,x_n) \neq 0$ by the equation $q_j(x_1,\ldots,x_n) \cdot y_j = 1$.

Comment: @Noam, thanks for this. I should have remembered this trick from GL_n and localizations at an element. However in contexts like group theory there is no such trick. 

Answer (score 2):

In algebraic geometry, it's called a *quasi-projective algebraic set*, which by definition is a Zariski open subset of a Zariski closed subset of projective space. (I'm assuming you only have finitely many $p_i$'s and finitely many $q_j$'s.) Since you're using non-homogeneous polynomials, you're starting in affine space, but that's simply projective space in the homogeneous variables $X_0,\ldots,X_n$ with the condition $X_0\ne0$, so it fits into your framework.

Comment: Thanks Joe.   I'm really looking though for the name of the set of equations and "anti"-equations rather than the set of points in affine space which they define. 

